Panel Data logistic regression
I am working with a panel dataset that describes company code as an id variable and fiscal year as a time variable (1500 firms from 2013-2022). The dependent variable is binary. First I checked for multicollinearity with vif in STATA:
regress dependent variable independent variables control variables

vif 

After this I did the following:
xtlogit dependent variable independent variables control variables i.year, fe
estimates store fe
xtlogit dependent variable independent variables control variables i.year, re
estimates store re
hausmann fe re

p value is less than 0.05, therefore I choose the conditional fixed-effects logistic regression.
To interpret the effects of predictor variables on the likelihood of a binary outcome, I used the odds ratio:
xtlogit dependent variable independent variables control variables i.year, fe or
Is this procedure correct? However, if I use conditional logistic regression with fixed effects, the number of observations is reduced from 7500 to 2500. Is this a problem?
Thank you very much for your help and thoughts!

What is the outcome variable and its frequency distribution?  What exactly does the p-value test?  Are you aware of the problems caused by using p-values to select models?  Also, consider a first order Markov process (one lag in Y) as detailed here to handle serial correlation.  Random intercepts assume correlations are constant no matter what the time gap.
